# I was trying to make a music player using c# Forms but I don't know how to make a search function to search for the songs from the list. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, search

This is the code that I used for the music player:

```
public partial class MusicPlayer : Form
{
    public MusicPlayer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    String[] paths, files;

    private void BtnSelectSongs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        ofd.Multiselect = true;

        if(ofd.ShowDialog()== System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            paths = ofd.FileNames;
            files = ofd.FileNames;

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                ListBoxSongs.Items.Add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ListBoxSongs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsMusic.URL = paths[ListBoxSongs.SelectedIndex];
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: A loop or Linq [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) ? Can you add more details, please ?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: @DanielMann I tried looking in StackOverflow and youtube,used google too

Comment: @OlivierRogier Do you mean those  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: Filenames is a string array. You can use for example Array.Find() to get what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `List<string>`

```
var songslist = new List<string>();

public void SearchMusic(string music)
{
if (songslist.Contains(music))
    string searchresult = songslist.ElementAt(songslist.IndexOf(music));
}
```